# Grep command with fields

Tags: bash, grep

I've a formatted text and I need to find a sequence of two characters A separated by two any characters. The point is that I need to look for them only in the second column of the formatted text. I need to use the grep command. I came up with this:

```
grep -E A\.\.\A data.txt
```

which works correctly for all the columns, but I need to search only in the second one. Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Post the sample input and the expected output please. Questions of these sort might invite a lot ambiguity otherwise for reasons such as what is the delimiter and so on.

Comment: Having said that, from your requirement, i suspect, `grep` is not the best tool. You may use `awk` as in  `awk '$2 ~ /A../' file` to achieve what you want. Awk has builtin variables that denote fields which make your job easy. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Using grep and assuming that `,` is your field separator, you can use something like this:

```
grep -E "^[^,]*,[^,]*A[^,]{2}A" data.txt
```

Here we

- skip the first column:

  - start of line `^`
  - everything up to the first comma `[^,]*`
  - the first comma `,`
- now that we are behind the first comma, e.g. in the second column, we match

  - optional characters `[^,]*` before the `A`
  - two characters that are not a comma: `[^,]{2}`
  - followed by the second `A`

But as others have already said: awk is probably the better tool for this task.

Comment: Thank you, I know that AWK would be a better solution, but I needed to do it with Grep. Thanks for the suggestions